# Getting the size of the char* array passed as an input to C++ function

Tags: arrays, char

I am trying to pass a character pointer array as an input from C test driver to C++ function (available in C wrapper)

```
char* LowerList[10];
LowerList[0]="abc";
LowerList[1]="def";
LowerList[2]="hij";
```

When available on the C++ side the values displayed for the the element is displayed as

```
char* LowerList[0]="abc";
LowerList[1]="def";
LowerList[2]="hij";
LowerList[3]=ƒì¶S<\$ UV<35?Ä@
LowerList[34]=ƒ<bad pointer>
```

I need to get the size of the array passed on to the C++ size which I could have got using 
while (LowerList[count]) but unable to do so because of the junk value.
Please let me know if any way I can find the correct size of the char* LowerList[] by initialising ,memory allocation or converting it to vector.

Corrected the above code for typo error

Here are my comments on some of the suggestions given to me so far:

1) Pass the size of the array as a parameter as well- A limitation for my scenario .2) Conversion to the vector need the size to be available 3) Sentinel value at which position I need to add . As stated earlier I am trying to handle a scenario where the user pass the value as 3 which leads to the failure.I don't have any control on restricting the way C user my C++ wrapper with his C test driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointers `LowerList[3]` through `LowerList[9]` are all uninitialized, if I'm not mistaken. You could always just use NULL as a sentinel value, and either assign it explicitly or do something like this:

```
char* LowerList[10] = { "abc", "def", "hij" };
```

This should initialize the remaining pointers in the array to NULL.

---

In response to your second comment:

```
#define LOWER_LIST_SIZE 10
#define MINIMUM_SIZE 2

#if LOWER_LIST_SIZE < MINIMUM_SIZE
    #error "LOWER_LIST_SIZE must be >= MINIMUM_SIZE"
#endif

char *LowerList[LOWER_LIST_SIZE] = // etc.
```

Or something like that.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#User-defined_compilation_errors_and_warnings

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have got the correct size with this initialisation .

Comment: One more point..is there a way I can initialise char* LowerList[10] in my C test driver without specifying the size as 10 as the code in the C wrapper accessing C++ function has access violation error if the size is less for example 2.The reason for this is to make my C test driver foolproof as the C test driver compilation is a success even with the size of 2 but it fails while executing it.

Comment: Thanks for your input.Is the same can be managed on the C++ side? As the minimum size is not known on the C side. I have tried a scenario in which the test drivers gives compilation error with value less than 3 ("Error: too many initialisers") while it works fine for the size more than 3. For exact size of 3 with three initialisers (char* LowerList[3] = { "abc", "def", "hij" };) the execution hits to streamsize _Count = (streamsize)_Traits::length(_Val); // may overflow (Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include)

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore, your initialization as given is totally wrong. You have:

```
char* LowerList[10]; 
char* LowerList[0]="abc"; 
char* LowerList[1]="def"; 
char* LowerList[2]="hij";
```

What you want is:

```
char* LowerList[10]; 
LowerList[0]="abc"; 
LowerList[1]="def"; 
LowerList[2]="hij";
```

or the alternative that JAB has. The issue with your version is that you are essentially declaring LowerList 4 times, but you can't do that.

Comment: Heh, somehow I completely missed that.